How to modify the concrete around channel drain so that water falls into the drain?
Following up on my DIY channel drain install, after one rainstorm, the channel is decent but not even 95% effective. Some water still comes in.
The problem was, during the concrete pour we vibrated the concrete too much, did not have enough weights on the plastic drain nor was the rebar deep enough to securely keep it fastened in position, and as a result the channel drain (the plastic part) lifted and set 1/4" above where it was suppose to.







It was finished about 2 weeks ago. It's not annoying enough that we want to jack-hammer the concrete and repour. I might do that in 15-20 years (or if the house is sold, it's not our problem).
But I was wondering if there's a way to address this issue. I though about drilling holes diagonally, through the Poured Concrete, and into the channel drain. Although it would give water a place to go, it wouldn't actually encourage water to flow into the drain.
Another thought I had was cutting wide (6") slots into the vinyl concrete patch, and cutting the side of the drain, so water can flow into the drain but I'm not sure if that'd be effective. It wouldn't look terrible since the slope isn't steep.

How do you feel about a speed bump?

Isn't the water that's coming in just what flowed down the door? You can't do much about that with a drain.

Start simple.
I have nearly the same grates in my garage slab. The difference is that I cut T-slots into my slab and only used the top grates, not the channel. Otherwise it's the same. You can pull out the grates and run them through a table saw to thin down the hanging ledge. If you go too far you'll reduce load capacity enough that they'll crack under a tire. Limit to about 1/8" (3mm).
Then, if that's not enough, look at milling the channel's shelf down another 1/8 inch. A router might be ok for this, or run a circular saw several times along the length.
Finally, do a little light shaping of the concrete with an angle grinder where it's needed most. Try to just bevel a bit for the least visual impact.

How thick is the plastic grating?
You may be able to get a thinner version of the grate or perhaps a version that would be inset into the drain. This would then allow you to grind down the concrete along the perimeter to lower the overall height of the grate.
Either option would require additional support underneath to support the weight of anything on the grate but it may reduce or eliminate the issue with the grate being too high.
First Step: Get a Digital Design file
A quick google search turned up hundreds of 3D print files for Drain cover replacements (3d print drain grate). Ideally you would find one for your specific drain. Most of these are free but the issue would be finding one for your specific measurements.
Alternatively you can go to a site such as Fiver.com where someone could create a CAD file for you based on the measurements of your existing drain grate.
Ideally you would get a STEP file as it is more flexible for output options since it can be used for 3D printing as well as for cutting (Laser, etc).
An STL file would work but is more related to 3D printing specifically.
Second Step: get the replacement drain grate 3D Printed (or Laser/CNC/Waterjet cut)
The fastest option would be if you have or know someone with a 3D printer.
Alternatively your could outsource the 3D printing to someone on Fiver or a commercial site.
Just be sure they use an appropriate 3D filament that is also opaque. The general consensus of filament for 3D printed outdoor use is ASA (PETG would be the second choice, ABS and PLA will become more brittle either from temperature or UV exposure).
Another option would be to have material cut using one of several methods (Laser, CNC or Waterjet cut). Depending on how the material is supported, this might be a better option for a more durable replacement grate.
I've heard good things about Send-Cut-Send. Here is a list of the materials that they can cut. You can also use the Send-Cut-Send Discount Link for a 15% discount (no affiliation).
Good luck and be sure to post an update with the results.

These grates are of FRP (fiber-reinforced plastic). Be sure any 3D printer uses a compatible material to retain vehicle load capability.
